# Mysql code,cursor inside stored proc not working

Tags: mysql

```
create procedure Studentinfo()

begin 
declare st int;

declare stu varchar(20);

declare  done int default false;

declare CURSOR  s1 for select sid,sname from student;

declare continue handler for not found set done =true;

open s1;

read1 :loop

fetch s1 into st,stu;

if done=true then

leave read1;

end if;


select concat(st,stu);

end loop read1;

close s1;

end;
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? What is happening? What isn't happening? The stored procedure alone tells us very little.

Comment: Oh,,,it tells that create stored procedure fails with error sql syntax erro..

Answer (score 1):

Actually you get a syntax error declare CURSOR s1 should be declare s1 CURSOR
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html